# Android: photo grid and slideshow

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gallery

Hi 
I need to implement a photo library with 2 screens. one with image thumbnails, when we click on any one of the thumbnail, need to display the 2nd screen with full image that fits into the entire screen, need to have "Prev", "Next", "back to gallary" links.

I can implement the 1st screen using GridView, can anybody help me how to develop the 2nd screen with slideshow.

Thanks in advance
Nehatha

Comment: Hi, can any body help me in this...